# Distorted layout getting generated from XML in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using this layout in one of my applications. I don't know why it is getting distorted. The main issue is that in all the three `LinearLayout` blocks, only the first `TextView` is displayed on the screen and in place of the `TextViews` following that, a big blank space is displayed.

The snapshot of the image being displayed is [Snapshot](http://i47.tinypic.com/eev11.png)...

**Layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5sp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_images"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10sp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/certification_image"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/details_image"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_details_page"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/details_image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ll_images"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/details_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ll_images"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_facts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_images">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_facts"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="Facts"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_tv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="@string/test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_tv3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_tv4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_foundation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_facts">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_foundation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="Foundation Statement"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_tv5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_overview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_foundation">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_overview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
            android:padding="10sp"
            android:text="Overview"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_tv6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewScorecard"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_overview"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_button"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp"
        android:text="@string/ViewScorecard"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what do you mean distorted?

Comment: Is there any screenshots??

Comment: @AndroSelva When I check the layout by entering temporary string in all textViews, it shows up a page which is too length (like 20 pages long) and also it doesnt display any text in any of the textViews.

Comment: please help us with a screenshot then

Comment: @AndroSelva I have attached the snapshot link in the edit.

Comment: @RKN Snapshot added now...

Comment: what do you have her "@string/test?

Comment: @AndroSelva It contains the value "Test string"... I just added this to test out the layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured it out... All I had to do was I had to add the following line to my `LinearLayout`.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Thanks all for the help...

Answer (score 0):

You forget about 
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Just change
`<RelativeLayout`
to
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`